# segmentAlongLine() returning line with a gap in the middle

Tags: arcpy, line, arcgis-10.7, segment

I'm trying to use `segmentAlongLine()` to return a portion of a polyline based on percentage in my feature class. It works for most of my lines in the feature class, but in some cases, the polyline returned contains a gap in the middle.

For example, here is the original polyline.
[image: This is what the original polyline looks like.]

When I create a new line using `polyline.segmentAlongLine(0, 0.5, True)`, I get the following line as an output:
[image: Polyline starting at 0 and ending at 50% end up with a gap in the middle.]

Has anyone else run into a similar issue or know what would be causing the gap? It happens for any value of `end_measure` greater than 0.27 (27%). I've also tried switching the `start_measure` and `end_measure` values but end up with the same issue.

I'm using Python 2.7 with ArcMap 10.7.1.

EDIT: one detail I failed to mention is the polyline is the result of a Dissolve with `"DISSOLVE_LINES"` set as my `unsplit_lines` attribute.

Comment: I would start by checking if your data contains multipart polylines.

Comment: I think it must be, one detail I forgot at add was that this line is the result of a Dissolve with  the "DISSOLVE_LINES" attribute set. How can I check if it contains multipart polylines to be sure?

Comment: Run add geometry attribute   part count on it anyway.  Method in question works like a charm. Also worth computing mid point.

Comment: Yes, after checking it definitely is a multipart polyline caused by the dissolve.  Does this mean I would have to reorder the parts within that multipart polyline in order for the segmentAlongLine to not result in the gap?